# renaming a locked table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When migrating a table to a new schema I want to make sure to have an atomic switch to the new table using the copy and rename procedure. Hence I am trying to rename a locked table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_new (...)

-- copy data to new table, might take very long
INSERT INTO foo_new (id,created_at,modified_at)
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id <= 3;

LOCK TABLES foo WRITE, foo_new WRITE;

-- quickly copy the tiny rest over
INSERT INTO foo_new (id,created_at,modified_at)
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id > 3;

-- now switch to the new table
RENAME TABLE foo TO foo_old, foo_new TO foo;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Unfortunately that results in `ERROR 1192 (HY000): Can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables or an active transaction`.

How should this be done differently?

This is with `mariadb:10.1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While in general Rick is right to use the Percona Tools (see [1](https://www.pythian.com/blog/important-caveats-when-using-pt-online-schema-change/) and [2](http://www.fromdual.com/online-ddl_vs_pt-online-schema-change)), the answer to the question really is to use `ALTER TABLE`. I thought `RENAME` was just an alias - but [it seems like that's not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988797/what-is-the-difference-between-alter-table-rename-and-rename-table).

Test seem to indicate that this works OK:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_new (...)

-- copy data to new table, might take very long
INSERT INTO foo_new (id,created_at,modified_at)
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id <= 3;

LOCK TABLES foo WRITE, foo_new WRITE;

-- quickly copy the tiny rest over
INSERT INTO foo_new (id,created_at,modified_at)
  SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id > 3;

-- now switch to the new table
ALTER TABLE foo RENAME TO foo_old;
ALTER TABLE foo_new RENAME TO foo;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_old (...)
LOCK TABLES foo WRITE; 
INSERT INTO foo_old (id,created_at,modified_at)
  SELECT * FROM foo;
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id <= 3;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

As the error message states, you can't use `RENAME TABLE` while having the same table locked.

Comment: what was wrong with the current method and what's the dfference in your answer?

Comment: The difference is, that you don't have to use `RENAME TABLE` which is not possible when the table is locked (see the error message in the question).

Comment: I have to use `rename table` as the other table has a different schema. Also not sure why the `delete`.

Comment: Because you only write `id > 3` entries into your new table, see your `SELECT` for the `INSERT`. What's the difference in the schema? Don't leave out such details in your question.

Comment: Right - but why would one delete `id > 3` then? If deleting then it would have to be `id <= 3`.

Comment: But anyway - this is no solution. I explicitly asked about a table rename. This is about the migration of a large table - which means the rename is essential.

Comment: Oh yes, right, `<= 3`, didn't care about this that much. But like I already said "you can't use RENAME TABLE while having the same table locked." My answer does basically the same thing. If you want, you can do an `ALTER TABLE`, too, I don't know, you're not providing the whole information necessary to answer the question. And I don't see what is so wrong about my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel...  Use Percona's `pt-online-schema-change`; it takes care of the details.

Answer (score 0):

"No data should be written or read between the LOCK and UNLOCK STATEMENT."

I met the same matter, and found the reason in MySQL Docs:

[MySQL8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rename-table.html)

```
As of MySQL 8.0.13, you can rename tables locked with a LOCK TABLES statement, provided that they are locked with a WRITE lock or are the product of renaming WRITE-locked tables from earlier steps in a multiple-table rename operation.
```

[MySQL5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html)

```
To execute RENAME TABLE, there must be no active transactions or tables locked with LOCK TABLES.
```

By the way, in MySQL 5.7, when table is locked by "LOCK tables tbl WRITE" statement, 
the lock will be released because of executing "ALTER TABLE tbl_0 RENAME TO tbl_1" 
and  strange behavior will be happening in the same session and new session.

```
# MySQL 5.7

# session 0
mysql> lock tables tbl_0 WRITE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE tbl_0 RENAME TO tbl_1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from tbl_1;
ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'tbl_1' was not locked with LOCK TABLES

# then start new session 
# session 1
mysql> select * from tbl_1;
...
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

# session 0
mysql> unlock tables;
```

Hope it could help.